# Python Metaclass: Create attributes for instance from the attribues for metaclass

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        # Generate a and b for the object based on x ?
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

class A(metaclass=Meta):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

obj = A(x)
```

The `x` passed to `A` should be consumed with in the meta class `Meta`, and it should generate the attributes `a` & `b` that are needed by the `__init__` of `A`. It is preferred for `obj` not to have access to `x`.

Not sure if its possible or valid, but is there a way to achieve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide a new `__call__` method for the type that computes `a` and `b` from `x` and passes them to the default `__call__` method.

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        # Generate a and b for the object based on x ?
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

    def __call__(cls, x):
        a, b = divmod(x, 10)
        return super().__call__(a, b)

class A(metaclass=Meta):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

obj = A(21)  # obj = Meta.__call__(A, 21), which calls type.__call__(A, 2, 1)
assert obj.a == 2 and obj.b == 1
```

---

In case this is an XY problem, you can define a separate class method that avoids the need for a custom metaclass.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    @classmethod
    def from_x(cls, x):
        a, b = divmod(x, 10)


obj = A.from_x(21)
```

The class method makes explicit in the source of `A` how you go from a one-argument function call to the "expected" two-argument initialization. It saves your caller from wondering how `A(21)` works when neither `A.__init__` nor the inherited `A.__new__` takes two arguments.

Comment: Thanks both the solution makes sense and works. `from_x` seems more cleaner and manageable.

Comment: Where possible, avoid defining a new metaclass. See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#determining-the-appropriate-metaclass; the "most derived metaclass" is not guaranteed to exist.